# How to restrict or give access to all of the function of a controller with some condition check in cakePHP 3.6

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to restrict or give access to all of my fuction inside a controller by checking some condition in cakephp 3.6. 
Suppose I have `add(), edit(), view($id)` function in my `PostController.php` . Now I have an input field where user will put an unique id. If this id is present in the database then I want to give access to those function. Oterwise it should show a message to the user.
I am new in cakePHP, so I don't have much idea about cakePHP. 
I have tried using beforeFilter. But it is not working.

Here is the code that I have tried. Right now I am not checking with database. Just checking if code is given in input field or not.

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    if(!empty($event->subject()->request->data)){

        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I know maybe those are not proper. But I am not getting proper idea even not proper documentation also.

Here is my controller code structure.

```
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class CodesController extends AppController
{

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    if(!empty($event->subject()->request->data)){

        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public function add()
{
    //code will be here
}
public function view($id)
{
    //code will be here
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `return true` from your `beforeFilter`, use:

```
$this->Auth->allow(['add', 'edit', 'view']);
```

No need to do anything in the false case.

Alternately, if those are your only functions, you can simplify to:

```
$this->Auth->allow();
```

More details [in the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public).

Comment: I am not using default auth function. I am trying to restrict using a 6 digit code. If code is valid then it should allow. Otherwise it should not.